# call a shinyapp saved as a function from a running shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

I have a running shinyapp (myapp) that during its run creates an object that can be used as in argin to another shinyapp (fun.app) that is saved as a function for further analysis.

How can I invoke fun.app from myapp?

This is a toy example of the problem

```
fun.app <- function(df){shinyApp(
 ui = fluidPage(
numericInput("n", "n", 1),
plotOutput("plot")
),
server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot( plot(df, input$n)) 
}
)}

shinyApp(
 ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton('go','push me')
),
server = function(input, output) {
observeEvent(input$go,{
  runApp(fun.app(cars))
})
})
```

I get this error

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6039 
Warning: Error in handlers$add: Key / already in use 
Stack trace (innermost first): 
70: handlers$add 
69: handlerManager$addHandler 
68: startApp 
67: runApp 
66: observeEventHandler [#7] 
4: <Anonymous> 
3: do.call 
2: print.shiny.appobj 
1: <Promise>
```